# rails 6 / webpacker tooltip and popover event listeners TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, webpacker

I'm getting the error TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function If I comment out tooltip only, then I get the same error for popover(is not a function) I had to remove the event listeners from application.js to stop the error I've seen suggested solutions that jquery-ui isn't installed but I found that requiring jquery-ui broke my app and so it's probably included in jquery-ujs and shouldn't be invoked on it's own but someone can advise me on that hopefully too

```
        document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
    //  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    //  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
    })
```

Here's my complete application.js

```
        require("@rails/ujs").start()
    require("turbolinks").start()
    require("jquery")
    require("js.cookie")
    require("@rails/activestorage").start()
    require("channels")
    require("react")
    require("react-dom")
    require("bootstrap")
    require.context('../images', true)
    import "bootstrap"
    import "blueimp-gallery"
    import "../stylesheets/application"
            document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
            //  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
            //  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
            })

    import JQuery from 'jquery';
    window.jQuery = $;
    window.$ = $;

    require("../stylesheets/application")
```

Comment: I do not see where the jQuery UI library being loaded anyplace. `.tooltip()` is a part of this library and if it's not included, you won't be able to load it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the rubygems jquery-ui-rails and while I was at it I threw in jquy-ui-themes.